# Using CSS classes to express state

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, state

Is it good practice to express the state of an HTML element--such as whether an input's value is valid--using a CSS class? Would it be better practice to use data attributes, the properties of a JavaScript object representing the element, or some other method? Example:

**CSS:**

```
.error {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px .1em #b94a48;
}
```

`.error` is appended to any input that fails validation. When the user attempts to proceed, jQuery checks for the class:

**JavaScript:**

```
if ($('#container').find('.error').length !== 0) {
    // Don't proceed.
}
```

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Comment: Slightly longer answer: This sort of thing tends to happen a lot when using jQuery. It's fairly common practice. If using a larger frontend framework, then state would probably be handled by that and not by CSS class.

Comment: If you wish to achieve WCAG compliance, or if you wish to cater to people with disabilities, use of only color to indicate an error will leave out people who are blind or colorblind. In addition to adding the `.error` class, consider using [aria-invalid](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/ARIA21.html) as well as a non-color-based visual indicator, such as an exclamation point adjacent to the field.

Comment: As a color blind developer, I can attest to this. I can barely tell the success green and the error red look apart in the recent project I've been working on. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using classes to track state is pretty common, for example - in AngularJS: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#css-classes

but - remember that css-classes are easily manipulated in the browser, so if you're doing anything other than decoration with the state classes, you may want to consider also saving state in a data-attribute as well (or controller if using a framework)